# Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView: UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to make a list containing names. This list should be modifiable (add, delete, sort, etc). However, whenever I tried to change the items in the ArrayAdapter, the program crashed, with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` error. Here is my code:

```
ListView panel = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.panel);
String[] array = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
panel.setAdapter(adapter);

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      adapter.insert("h", 7);
   }
});
```

I tried insert, remove and clear methods, and none of them worked. Would someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

I tried it out myself and found it didn't work, so I checked out the source code of [ArrayAdapter](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) and found out the problem: The `ArrayAdapter`, on being initialized by an array, converts the array into an `AbstractList` (`List<String>`) which cannot be modified.

**Solution**
Use an `ArrayList<String>` instead using an array while initializing the ArrayAdapter.

```
String[] array = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"}; 
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me hours of frustration. Would you mind explain to me why String[] didn't work?

Comment: @Ryan you can't insert into an array, you can into a list, unless the list implementation doesn't allow it. If your backing data is not going to change, ArrayAdapter allows you to use a more memory efficient technique.

Comment: @st0le what difference it makes if I pass "new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array))" or just "Arrays.asList(array)"? The first works and the second doesn't.

Comment: @golosovsky, In the first one, you create a Mutable List, the second way creates a Immutable List. (cannot be modified once created)

Comment: An insert in an array is quite possible, Arrays.copyOf and System.arraycopy will do the trick. I think a developer of the API was simply lazy

Comment: How will you update the reference of the original array that was passed to the adapter with the copy? It's a clean design decision, your comments are very callous.

Comment: It's 2016 and still this ridiculous exception thrown at this specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe they'll never document this out, or stop allowing immutables if they plan to provide something like notifyDatasetChanged