# Why can't one add/remove items from an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-2.2-froyo

I am using an `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` to populate the items to list in a `android.widget.Spinner`. That works all fine.

But now I want to keep the list of items dynamic, i.e. I want to be able to add/remove items from the selection list at runtime. However, when I call `adapter.add(item)` or `adapter.remove(item)` I always get a `UnsupportedOperationException`, even though the Javadocs of the `ArrayAdapter` class describe these two methods as to be usable for exactly that intended purpose.

Is this a bug, really not implemented or what am I missing here?

Comment: I think a snippet could help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview)

Answer (score 121):

You probably initialized the adapter with a plain Java array (e.g., `String[]`). Try using something that implements the `java.util.List` interface (e.g., `ArrayList<String>`).

Comment: I'm using an ArrayList<Form> and I getting `UnsupportedOperationException`. Form is a custom class.

Comment: Except when using Arrays.asList which returns a read-only ArrayList. See Zeratul's answer below

Comment: I initialed with `Collections.<String>emptyList()`, it died too. `new ArrayList<String>)` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 22):

I know it's late but just a quick explanation: it's because method Arrays.asList(T... array) returns custom inner class named **ArrayList** that is **read-only**. As already said, you need to provide full impl. e.g. java.util.ArrayList.

Answer (score 16):

Here's the source code of `ArrayAdapter#remove`:

```
public void remove(T object) {
    if (mOriginalValues != null) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mOriginalValues.remove(object);
        }
    } else {
        mObjects.remove(object);
    }
    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The only thing that can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` there is the line in the else-block. So the problem is that the list you're using doesn't support removing items. My guess is you're using an array. Try an ArrayList, for instance.

*edit: So yeah, what Mark said...*

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem, my data was saved in resource String Array, so I was creating ArraAdapter with **createFromResource**.
The following code for creating ArrayAdapter from resource String Array solved the problem:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] cities = res.getStringArray(R.array.cities_array);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
     this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
     new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(cities)));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your adapter Class - Delete an Item

```
remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Add an Item -

```
adapter.add (newItem);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
```

Comment: adapter.remove requires object, not position. And throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are using List in your **ArrayAdapter** class instead of **ArrayList**.

Try converting your array or list to **ArrayList** -

```
new ArrayList<ClassType>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(recentlyClient))
```

Example code how to implement:

```
String[] recentlyClient;

ArrayAdapter<String> recenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(recentlyClient)));
```

Answer (score 0):

My nightmare was removing items from the `ArrayAdapter<String>`. I have been avoiding this method for almost 6 years because of this phenomenon :(

My Adapter was been:

```
 private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final Bitmap[] slike;
    private final String[] nazivi;
    private final String[] grad_freq;
    private final boolean[] omiljeni;

    MyAdapter (Context c, Bitmap[] slike, String[] nazivi, String[] grad_freq, boolean[] omiljeni) {
        super(c, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, nazivi);
        this.context = c;
        this.slike = slike;
        this.nazivi = nazivi;
        this.grad_freq= grad_freq;
        this.omiljeni = omiljeni;
    }
// ...
}
```

And now, it look like:

```
 private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Bitmap> slike;
    private final ArrayList<String> nazivi;
    private final ArrayList<String> grad_freq;
    private final ArrayList<Boolean> omiljeni;

    MyAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> slike, ArrayList<String> nazivi, ArrayList<String> grad_freq, ArrayList<Boolean> omiljeni) {
        super(c, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, nazivi);
        this.context = c;
        this.slike = slike;
        this.nazivi = nazivi;
        this.grad_freq= grad_freq;
        this.omiljeni = omiljeni;
    }
// ...
}
```

Of course, after deleting the desired items, be sure to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks for answers here.

Answer (score 0):

I think `String []` has got the fixed size. So, we cannot add or remove element from it. So, When we want to remove element from the adapter which populated by `string []` , the exception `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown.

So, for this workaround we have to populate the adapter with `java.util.List` interface (e.g., `ArrayList<String>`).