# UnsupportedOperationException with ArrayAdapter.remove

Tags: java, android, adapter

In my code I have a `ListActivity`.  One of the context menu options for a list item is "delete", which opens a dialog confirming the action.  I intended to implement this functionality by first deleting the item's data in the database and then removing it from the `ArrayAdapter`.  It is in removing it from the `ArrayAdapter` that I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`...

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{
    asynchronousDeleteEntry(CONTEXT_SELECTED_ID);
    dialog.dismiss();                          

    //I -know- that the adapter will always be an object
    //of ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry> because this is the only type
    //I ever call setListAdapter with.  Debugging confirms this
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<JournalEntry>)
        journalViewerListActivity.this.getListAdapter();

    //EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE                                
    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(CONTEXT_SELECTED_POSITION));

    //refreshes the ListView to show the new items
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that this problem crops up when you initialize your `ArrayAdapter` with an array. Try initializing it with a `List<JournalEntry>`. Reference: [Why can't one add/remove items from an ArrayAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476723/why-cant-one-add-remove-items-from-an-arrayadapter)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to modify list which is declared as `final`. Compiler tried to warn you, but you've suppressed warning by  `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: That is not what "final" means. It's not the same as C++ "const".