# ArrayAdapter remove does not work

Tags: android, listview, adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UnsupportedOperationException with ArrayAdapter.remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200331/unsupportedoperationexception-with-arrayadapter-remove)

I have a listview which will be refreshed when the user clicks a delete button.
For some reason I get this error

> 02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:645)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:77)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:230)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.remove(ArrayAdapter.java:212)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at com.DCWebMakers.Vairon.ManageAppointment.onClick(ManageAppointment.java:102)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   02-19 17:16:47.231: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is the code when removing the item.

```
detailAdapter.remove(eDelete.getText().toString());
detailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200331/unsupportedoperationexception-with-arrayadapter-remove

Comment: It looks like you may be initializing the ArrayAdaptor with an actual array instead of an ArrayList

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the stack trace, the list that is backing your `ArrayAdapter` does not support removal.  What type of list are you using?