# Custom ListView Adapter throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

[This is the tutorial that I followed](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) to use a custom Listview Adapter. The problem I am having is that when I try to clear the adapter, the app crashes and throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

```
if(adapter != null) {
    adapter.clear();
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
private void setListViewAdapterToDate(int month, int year, int dv)
{
     if(summaryAdapter != null) {
        summaryAdapter.clear();
     }

    setListView(month, year, dv);
    summaryList.addAll(Arrays.asList(summary_data));
    summaryAdapter = new SummaryAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_item_row, summaryList);


    summaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    calendarSummary.setAdapter(summaryAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Some more context on when you're calling adapter.clear() would help. Perhaps you're calling it inside of a thread. I'd post all your code if it's not too long. If it is, just the surrounding code. Also, post the entire error stack trace you see in the logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking around a bit, it would seem that initializing the adapter with an array is the problem. See [UnsupportedOperationException with ArrayAdapter.remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200331/unsupportedoperationexception-with-arrayadapter-remove) and [Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView: UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview)

Try using an `ArrayList` instead of an `array` like so

```
ArrayList<Weather> weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>()
weather_data.add( new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy") );
// continue for the rest of your Weather items.
```

If you're feeling lazy, you can convert your `array` to an `ArrayList` this way

```
ArrayList<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<Weather>();
weatherList.addAll(Arrays.asList(weather_data));
```

To finish the conversion to `ArrayList` in your `WeatherAdapter` class you will want to remove the `Weather data[] = null;` and all of it's references (such as inside the constructor) because `ArrayAdapter` holds the data for you and you can access it with [getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int))

So inside of your `getView` function you would change `Weather weather = data[position];` to `Weather weather = getItem(position);`

**Update**
Modify your udated code with

```
private void setListViewAdapterToDate(int month, int year, int dv)
{
    setListView(month, year, dv); 
     if(summaryAdapter != null) {
        summaryAdapter.clear();
        summaryAdapter.addAll( summaryList );
        summaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     } else {
         summaryList.addAll(Arrays.asList(summary_data));
         summaryAdapter = new SummaryAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_item_row, summaryList);
     }
    calendarSummary.setAdapter(summaryAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. The only thing now is that when I try to clear the `ArrayList`, it still doesn't clear rather it appends to the previous list. I've updated the question with the code. Please check.

Comment: You should still use the adapter.clear() method rather than the list. Is ```adapter.clear()``` still giving you the error? Btw, I edited my answer a few times so you might now have seen the latest yet.

Comment: No, it doesn't give an error now. All it does is now append the previous list data to the current one instead of refreshing/replacing it.

Comment: Are you using ```adapter.clear();```? The code you posted above says ```weatherList.clear();```

Comment: what is the difference between using an array list or an array??

Comment: Array was throwing the error `UnsupportedOperationException` if I added `adapter.clear()`. If I removed it, the code worked fine but it appended the data to previous list. ArrayList doesn't throw the exception when using `adapter.clear()` but it doesn't clear the data either.

Comment: Ah, it's because you are adding to the list itself. ```summaryList.addAll(Arrays.asList(summary_data));``` You should use the adapter to add more items. See the [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)) function.

Comment: From what I see the code isn't set up quite right. You should only initialize the ```summaryList``` and the ```summaryAdapter``` once. Then when you want to update it some more you can use the ```summaryAdapter.clear()``` and ```summaryAdapter.add()``` or ```summaryAdapter.remove()``` methods. Try not to manipulate the ```summaryList``` after you have initialized it. If things still don't work you will have to post all the code.

Comment: @Pzanno, what do I add to the adapter? summary_data or summaryList?

Comment: After it's initialized you add new ```Weather``` objects. So ```summaryAdapter.add( new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy") )``` but given the code you have I'll post an updated answer to try and work with what you have.