# Remove item from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to implement remove item (because it's stating to update from 0 to 1 from listView in Android when user press textView in each item. e.g:
There are 3 items

- apple 0
- orrange 0
- grape 0

In each item there is a textView as a button. When user press textView for Apple, my app will update item 'apple' to 1, and remove it from listView, and in listview 'apple' will be gone.
This is my list code

```
public class ListPelangganUnsyncFragment extends ListFragment
{
    AdapterListPelanggan pelangganAdp;
    ArrayList<Pelanggan> pelanggan = null;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    Button sync;
    int list = 0;
    int newList = 0;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pelanggan, container, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
//        Buat kalo udah ada login
//        SharedPreferences setting

        pelanggan = new ArrayList<Pelanggan>();

//        Buat ngambil data dari DB lokal
        final DBPelanggan dbpel = new DBPelanggan(getActivity()); // get context dri activity, return null klo fragment ini ga attach
        try
        {
            dbpel.open();
            pelanggan = dbpel.getDataPelanggan();
            dbpel.close();
            list = pelanggan.size();
            Log.d("List", list+"");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sync = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sinkron);
        Button add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addPelanggan);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), FormPelangganActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fungsi", 0);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        sync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    dbpel.open();
                    dbpel.updateStat(pelanggan);
                    pelanggan = dbpel.getDataPelanggan();
                    dbpel.close();
                    if(pelanggan != null)
                    {
                        pelangganAdp = new AdapterListPelanggan(getActivity(), R.layout.isi_list_pelanggan, pelanggan);
                        listView.setAdapter(pelangganAdp);
                    }
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).selectFragment(0);

                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });




        //Adapter

        listView.setClickable(true);
        if(pelanggan != null)
        {
            pelangganAdp = new AdapterListPelanggan(getActivity(), R.layout.isi_list_pelanggan, pelanggan);
            listView.setAdapter(pelangganAdp);

            newList = listView.getCount();
            Log.d("List", newList + "");
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

and this is my adapter:

```
public class AdapterListPelanggan extends ArrayAdapter<Pelanggan>
{
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private ArrayList<Pelanggan> arPelanggan;
    Holder h = null;
    DBPelanggan db;
    private boolean status;

    // Holder = Object
    static class Holder
    {
        TextView tv_KTP, tv_Nama;
        ImageView syncButton;
    }

    public AdapterListPelanggan(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Pelanggan> arPelanggan)
    {
        super(context, resource, arPelanggan);

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.arPelanggan = arPelanggan;

        Log.d("ListAdapter", "Jumlah List c "+arPelanggan.size());
    }

    public AdapterListPelanggan(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Pelanggan> arPelanggan, boolean status)
    {
        super(context, resource, arPelanggan);

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.arPelanggan = arPelanggan;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        h = new Holder();
        final Pelanggan pelanggan = arPelanggan.get(position); // Set Data per urutan
        Log.d("ListAdapter", "ID Pelanggan b "+pelanggan.getId_pelanggan()+"");
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            h.tv_KTP = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ktp_isi_lp);
            h.tv_Nama = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_isi_lp);
            h.syncButton = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.syncButton);

            if(status)
            {
                h.syncButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            convertView.setTag(h);
        }
        else
        {
            h = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        // ------------------ Button Sync ------------------

        h.syncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try
                {
                    db = new DBPelanggan(getContext());
                    db.open();
                    db.updateStatPelanggan(pelanggan);
                    Log.d("ListAdapter", "ID hilang " + pelanggan.getId_pelanggan());
                    arPelanggan.remove(pelanggan);
                    arPelanggan = db.getDataPelanggan();
                    Log.d("ListAdapter", "Jumlah List c "+arPelanggan.size());


         Log.d("ListAdapter", pelanggan.getId_pelanggan()+"ID Sekarang");
                db.close();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    h.tv_KTP.setText(pelanggan.getId_pelanggan());
    h.tv_Nama.setText(pelanggan.getNama());

    return convertView;
}


}
```

The problem is when I press textView for 'apple', indeed it was updated in db and gone from my list, but when I press 'orrange' after press 'apple' my app gives error.

This is my error:

> 11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.michael.ims_application_apps.AdapterListPelanggan.getView(AdapterListPelanggan.java:63)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2260)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5045)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3202)
>       11-17 10:34:55.639 5429-5429/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3476)

Anyone can advice me how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: what is your line no 63 in your adapter

Comment: Try logging the size of the `arPelanggan` before this line: `final Pelanggan pelanggan = arPelanggan.get(position);`

Comment: line no 63 is final Pelanggan pelanggan = arPelanggan.get(position); @sud

Comment: @EricB. wait I will try it first

Comment: the `position` variable have value greater than your array list length..

Comment: The position almost certainly will be larger than the arraylist but the real question is why, seems like your notifyDataSetChanged isn't doing what you want it to. There is some discrepancy between the position in the list you are clicking and the underlying arraylist

Comment: @EricB. Still error, first arPelangga size was 9, and I tried to remove, it become 8, and when I removed again it become 7, but error, same error

Comment: Why are you getting new data from db after removing at this line? `arPelanggan = db.getDataPelanggan();`

Comment: @EricB. my first idea is after update, I take new data. But thank you for your help, the problem was that code. Gratia, mate

Comment: Glad i could help you out, shall i post it as answer?

Comment: @EricB. Yes please, mate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove item in ArrayAdapter<String> in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444671/remove-item-in-arrayadapterstring-in-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line,

```
  arPelanggan = db.getDataPelanggan();
```

You are reloading the data from db after removing.

Answer (score 0):

check below line of code in your getview. what value you are getting in `position` variable, it may be greater than length of your array list->

```
final Pelanggan pelanggan = arPelanggan.get(position);
```