# Android - Array add to exsist ArrayAdapter (ListView)

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

How i can do array add to exsist ArrayAdapter?

This is the first call:

```
ArrayAdapterMessage adapter = new ArrayAdapterMessage(this, m_id, m_von_user, m_user_id, m_username, m_name, m_pic_id, m_zeit, m_msg);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: A little more detail would be nice. From what I understand your question to be asking though, I think you need to first update your array data and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). This call simply

"Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself"

Comment: Are you trying to add ANOTHER array to your adapter, or just update the existing array's data? If you're trying to add another array, you're going to also have to update the constructor of your ArrayAdapterMessage class, as well as the getView method(or whichever is responsible for binding)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview)