# Change values of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'd like to update values of my ArrayAdapter if the first element is selected :

```
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] categoriesArray;    
...

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoriesArray);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        if(arg2== Consts.GAME_CATEGORY_POSITION){

            adapter.clear();

            //Add new values to array
            categoriesArray = new String[subCategories.size()];
            for (int i=0; i<subCategories.size(); i++) {
                categoriesArray[i] = subCategories.get(i).getSub_name();                    
            }           
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
        }           
    }           
});
```

But the clear method (adapter) triggered an exception

```
12-27 09:37:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1423): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
12-27 09:37:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
12-27 09:37:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
12-27 09:37:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
12-27 09:37:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
12-27 09:37:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
```

Any idea ?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: where did you initialize your `categoriesArray` for the firstTime ?

Comment: check out answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass your own list instead of array to adapter. Adapter converts array to list using `Arrays.asList` method and list returned by this method doesn't support removal. You can create instance of `ArrayList` from your array and pass it to adapter:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(categoriesArray));
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

But better check very similar question mentioned by @PrafulBhatnagar: [Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView: UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview)

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to reinitialize the adapter, if you just want to change the data set. Try the following code -

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(categoriesArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

check out answer to this post

[Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView: UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview)

As per this post you should use `ArrayList` in place of string array...