# Having trouble deleting a listitem on click

Tags: java, android, listview

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this code. When I click a list item to open the delete dialog, it won't do anything. Though if I restart the activity, all items will be deleted.

```
 public class ContextsList extends Activity {


EditText display;
ListView lv;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Button addButton;
String temp_appender;
String appender = "";

List<String> dataset;
String[] splitup;
public String items;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contexts_list);

    display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    LoadPreferences();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    LoadPreferences();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            appender = LoadPreferences();
            if(display.getText().toString() != null){
                temp_appender = display.getText().toString();
                String string_to_split = appender + "," + temp_appender;
                List<String> items = Arrays.asList(string_to_split.split(","));
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SavePreferences("LISTS", string_to_split);

                LoadPreferences();
            }
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            deleteItem(arg1);
        }
    });

}

protected void deleteItem(final View arg1)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you want to delete \"" + 
    ((TextView) arg1).getText() +   "\"?");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            items = LoadPreferences();
            try {
                adapter.remove(((TextView) arg1).getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                SavePreferences("LISTS", items);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
            SavePreferences("LISTS", items);
        }

    });
    dialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    AlertDialog deleteDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    deleteDialog.show();
}


protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();


}

protected String LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dataSet = data.getString("LISTS", "");
    dataset = Arrays.asList(dataSet.split(","));
    splitup = dataSet.split(",");

    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(dataSet.split(","));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return dataSet;

}

}
```

I've been at this for hours, so if anyone could help spot this error I'd really appreciate it. Just let me know if you need any more input from me.

Comment: Don't do `catch (Exception ignored) { }` since that hides all the errors.

Comment: Does it crash or simply do nothing? I think you have to do as zapl says first about ignoring the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview-unsupportedoperationexception)

The reason is following: according to [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) the list is immutable in terms of adding/deletion. But on `add` operation you create a new adapter, so it runs well. But when you try to delete an object from "immutable" list, you get an error.

And please, never ever ever use empty `catch` block without clear explanation why it is empty. Just put `ignored.printStackTrace();` is will save you a tonn of time!

Answer (score 0):

Hai in my project i am doing list deletion. I am using like this. when the user click the list. please get the position of the list and pass through dialog function arg.

```
lv.remove(positiontoDelete);
```