# remove the selected item from the spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am newbie i want to remove the selected item from the `spinner` and also add the new item to the `spinner`.How can i do that.What i am trying is

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.slot , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            slotTime.setAdapter(adapter);
    slotTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                selectedTime = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    adapter.remove((String) slotTime.getSelectedItem());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

I got the error like this....

```
     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Anyone kindly help me to overcome this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView: UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: Just google "ArrayAdapter UnsupportedOperationException" and there you have it. It's not so hard nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

your data is immutable `(R.array.slot)`

So you can modify it

You need to store data in `List<String>`, pass it to `ArrayAdapter`. Now you can modify data by modify `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array in the `ArrayAdapter` class it converts the array into an `AbstractList`. This is an implementation of the `List` interface where elements cannot be added nor removed, i.e, immutable. What you should do is pass in an `ArrayList` by converting the array to a list. `Arrays.asList` method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

used below code for remove spinner value and notify.
here in strings as List.

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            strings.remove(arrstrings.indexOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()));
         //   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```