# How to add a single item to an existing spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner, adapter

I have a spinner, which already contains some items. I'm trying to add a new item to it after getting it from another activity by setResult and onActivityResult:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null 
    {...}
    else if(requestCode == GET_NEW_STUDENT_NAME)
    {
        String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)studentsSpinner.getAdapter();
        adapter.add(name);
        studentsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

However, every time the code runs, the activity closes. This exception is being shown:

> 03-29 19:20:30.925 26953-26953/com.example.user.privatelessons E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.user.privatelessons, PID: 26953
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.user.privatelessons/com.example.user.privatelessons.AddLessonActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4179)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4222)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1581)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
>           at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
>           at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:236)
>           at com.example.user.privatelessons.AddLessonActivity.onActivityResult(AddLessonActivity.java:123)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7121)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4175)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4222) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1581) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)

[EDIT]: At start, I initialize the spinner with following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, db.GetStudentslist());;
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*GetStudentslist()* returns String[].

The following code, which just shows the name in the logcat (without adding it to spinner), works fine:

```
 if(requestCode == GET_NEW_STUDENT_NAME && data != null)
            {
                String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
/*                List<String> names = Arrays.asList(db.GetStudentslist());
                names.add(name);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);;
                studentsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/
                Log.e("Name", name);
            }
```

Comment: Show the code of setting the spinner

Comment: Also your data and adapter

Comment: @gogolon please add full exception, not only one line.

Comment: @gogolon Please add whole content of the `onActivityResult()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that Make **List<> Variable,ArrayAdapter Globally above onCreate Method.**
add defaults items in oncreate Method and configure Arrayadapter for that spinner.

Then in onActivityResult add that new value in List.add("String").

After that add this line. 
**adapter.notifydatasetchanges();** 
it will update your data into spinner control.

If need more help i will give attach example here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store output from the method `db.GetStudentslist()` to some field (list) in your class (Activity). And when you would like to add/remove/change elements just modify list, and update it in adapter.

I created simple example:

### Activity

```
package training.com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // List with three predefined elements
    private List<String> listOfElements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            "Hello world", "Hello world", "Hello world"
    ));

    // Adapter for the Spinner
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private Spinner spinner;

    private Button addButton;
    private Button removeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize adapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfElements);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.action_bar_spinner);

        addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        removeButton = findViewById(R.id.remove_button);

        // Set adapter
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Add new element to the list
            listOfElements.add("Hello world");
        });

        removeButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Remove last item from the list
            int lastIndex = listOfElements.size() - 1;
            listOfElements.remove(lastIndex);
        });
    }
}
```

### With simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Expected output

[image: Layout]

---

If you receiving data in `onActivityResult()` you can do it in the same way:

```
// Read data
String name = data.getStringExtra("name");

// Add to list
listOfElements.add(name);
```

---

Remember to start activity properly:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_NEW_STUDENT_NAME);
```

and if you want to send data back:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("name",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

and in your `onActivityResult()` method you have to check two conditions:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    // Check result
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // And check what was requested
        if (requestCode == GET_NEW_STUDENT_NAME) {
            String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            listOfElements.add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing the list is a good idea, but it didn't help. It looks like it has something to do with onActivityResult method, which the code is put inside of. I finally got an excepton (it's not thrown every time for some reason). I edited my question to make it clear. Sorry for not doing it before.

Comment: That's what I checked last time, but the exception keeps appearing.

Comment: @gogolon you are NOT checking `resultCode` for this Activity. Check my example.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. It turned out that this question is a duplicate of [Unable to modify ArrayAdapter in ListView: UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200551/unable-to-modify-arrayadapter-in-listview-unsupportedoperationexception)